# Capture trailing / leading whitespice around a patterned if it exists?

Tags: javascript, regex

Suppose you want to replace a searched for string in a body of text and replace and "highlight" it i.e. wrap it in a `<span>` with a css class:

```js
const highlight = (str, ptn) => {
  if (ptn === '') return str
  str.replace(new RegExp(ptn, 'g'), `<span class="highligh">${ptn}</span>`)
}
```

How can I modify this regex pattern to include a leading / training whitespace if it exists? as the span will not care about the whitespace it is surrounded by and the pattern `ptn` might be part of a word...

```
example   str            ptn      res (as appears when render)
1         this is a str  is       thisisa str
2         this is a str  i        thisis a str
3         this is a str  t        this is a str
4         this is a str  his      thisis a str
```

so for example 4 the replacement for his would capture the trailing `" "`

Comment: @anubhava this won't work. It will break up a word if `ptn` is in the middle of a word. I address this in the post

Answer (score 1):

Not sure to well understand what the result should be, but is this what you want:

```js
const highlight = (str, ptn) => {
  if (ptn === '') return str
  return str.replace(new RegExp('\\s+'+ptn+'|'+ptn+'\\s+', 'g'), `<span class="highligh">${ptn}</span>`)
}

var test = [
    'is',
    'i',
    't',
    'his',
];
test.map(function(a) {
console.log(highlight('this is a str', a));
});
```

Comment: very close I made two small changes ``` let re = `\\s+${ptn}\\s+|\\s+${ptn}|${ptn}\\s+` ``` and 
```str.replace(new RegExp(re, 'g'), (p)=>`<span class="highligh">${p}</span>`) ```

Answer (score 0):

I would use directly the regex for matching leading/trailing white-space.

```js
var str = 'this is a str his';
var result = str.replace(/( )*his( )*/g, (p)=>`<span>${p}</span>`)
console.log(result);
```

Comment: try ```str.replace(/s*his/g, (p)=>`<span>${p}</span>`)``` and you will see that your solution does not include the spaces captured